# sequelize getAssociation for hasMany relation

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

`Billing` and `Particular` has `1:m` relationship. so,
`Billing.hasMany(Particular, {as: 'particulars', foreignKey: 'billing_id'})`

Now, I would like to grab one of the several particulars for given billing also make sure the billing exists in first place.

**GET /api/billings/:billingId/particulars/:particularId**

```
async function getParticular(req, res, next) {

    try {

    let billing;
    let result;

    billing = await Billing.findById(req.params.billingId);

    if(!billing) {
        throw new Error('Billing Not found');
    }

    result = await billing.getParticular(req.params.particularId);
    //Oh, wait, but billing.getParticular is not a function

    if(!result) {
        throw new Error('Particular Not found');
    }

    res.json(result);

    } catch (e) {
        next(e)
    }

}
```

How am I supposed to grab one of many particulars?

Comment: When you get your billing object, it should contain a list of particulars. Why do you want to make another request with the particular id?

Comment: `billing` does not contain `particulars`. They could be eager loaded though. In mongodb I could do `billing.particulars.id(particularId)`. I was expecting something similar to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are looking for is [`getParticulars`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/api/associations/has-many/#getassociationsoptions-promisearrayinstance), which returns list of related model instances basing on `where` attribute of passed `options`

```
result = await billing.getParticulars({ where: { id: req.params.particularId } });
```

`result` would be an array of particulars having `id = 1`, so probably single element array.

Comment: This is it :) . `let [result] = await billing.getParticulars({ where: { id: req.params.particularId } });`